# How do I apply a texture over a material in OpenGL ES?

Tags: textures, opengl-es, materials

How can I apply a texture over a material?

I've set up an object with the following material:

```
GLKBaseEffect *effect;
effect.colorMaterialEnabled = false;
effect.material.ambientColor = GLKVector4Make(251.0/255.0, 95.0/255.0, 96.0/255.0, 1.0);
effect.material.diffuseColor = GLKVector4Make(251.0/255.0, 95.0/255.0, 96.0/255.0, 1.0);
```

and it is correctly rendered with a pink color.

However, when I apply a texture with:

```
GLKTextureInfo * info = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:...];
effect.texture2d0.name = info.name;
effect.texture2d0.enabled = true;
```

the material seems to disappear and I just see the texture; the object is transparent where the texture is not visible, instead of being pink.

---

Here's an example:

The texture is created with the following code:

```
- (UIImage*)generateTexturefromText:(NSString*)text {
    NSError *error;

    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    myLabel.text = text;
    myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:"Helvetica" size:50];
    myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    myLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:0/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:1];
    myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    myLabel.numberOfLines = -1;
    myLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(myLabel.bounds.size, NO, 1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, 0);
    CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 1.0);
    [myLabel.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *layerImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if (error) {
        NSLog(" Error loading texture from image: %",error);
        return nil;
    }

    return layerImage;
}
```

Why is no color visible where the texture is transparent?

[image: texture over material]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved!

```
effect.texture2d0.envMode = GLKTextureEnvModeDecal;
```

It is related to the Texture Environment Parameters, i.e. how OpenGL combines the diffuse color of the material with the texture value.

As described here: [khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glTexEnv.xml](http://khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glTexEnv.xml). If I'm right that GLKit instruction should correspond to:

```
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
```

Comment: You should really flesh this out more. Tell us why it works, what it does, etc.

Comment: Done, hope it helps :)